# LXTerminal and XTerm Resize Command

Tags: command-line, bash, xterm, lxterminal

I want to execute a command in a bash script that will resize the terminal window. In xterm

`xterm -geometry=30x30`

will create a **new** xterm window, and

`lxterminal --geometry=30x30`

will create a **new** lxterminal window.

Is there a way to resize either terminal without opening a new window? This is what it would look like:

```
if [ $TERMINALTYPE=xterm ]; then
    DASH="-"
else
    DASH="--"
endif

echo -e $TERMINALTYPE" "$DASH"geometry 30x30"
```

**BUT:** If there is a command that is a nice one-liner that will work with either terminal (vt100 escape sequence maybe) then that is even better.

Comment: If you have Lubuntu, why don't you edit `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` instead of this scripting route?

Comment: @vasa1 I am running a script that will change the window to be the right size because it is an app. I don't want it to open like this every time, just when I run the app.

Comment: Modifying the file I mentioned will let you change the size of the *existing active window* to whatever dimensions you wish whenever you wish. You do so by pressing a couple of keys such as `Super+up arrow` or whatever. Other times, your window size will remain the default.

Comment: Have you looked into resizing your window with [wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) yet? It's a CL tool that directly communicates with your window manager and works for all applications. [Here are some examples of its usage](http://spiralofhope.com/wmctrl-examples.html).

Comment: @MHC Yes. I am looking for a builtin xterm resizing command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two steps to this. First, you need to tell xterm to allow it to happen at all, because by default it ignores requests by hosted programs to resize the window. Add this to your ~/.Xdefaults:

```
xterm*allowWindowOps: true
```

For this to take effect, you either have to log out, or run:

```
xrdb ~/.Xdefaults
```

Then launch a new xterm, and in your bash script:

```
echo -ne "\e[8;30;30t"
```

Comment: Thanks! Some remarks and *going further* in [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1238262/295207)

Answer (score 4):

Just want to share:

```
apt-get install xterm
```

Use the following resize command where **20** = no of rows, **40** = no of columns:

```
resize -s 20 40
```

Change the value of rows and columns as per requirement.

Answer (score 1):

### In addition to [@Paul's correct answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/297176/295207):

You could try this without editing `~/.Xdefaults`, by running:

```
xterm -xrm 'xterm*allowWindowOps: true'
```

Then, in new window:

```
printf "\e[8;%d;%dt" $[LINES+5] $[COLUMNS+5]
```

### `.Xdefaults` or `.Xresources`

Depending on your installation, you may have to store this on `.Xresources` instead of `.Xdefaults`.

> FILES
>
> Xrdb does not load any files on its own, but many desktop environments use `xrdb` to load `~/.Xresources` files on session startup to initialize the resource database,  as  a  generalized  replacement for `~/.Xdefaults` files.

Then after

```
sed -e '$axterm*allowWindowOps: true' -i.bak .Xresources 
xrdb <.Xresources
```

Then...

### Some `bind` samples

You could run this or **add to your `.bashrc`**:

```
# Some bind for 'Shift' + <direction> key and allowWindowOps resource
bind -x '"\e[1;2C"':'printf  "\e[8;%d;%dt" $LINES $((COLUMNS+5))'
bind -x '"\e[1;2D"':'printf  "\e[8;%d;%dt" $LINES $((COLUMNS-5))'
bind -x '"\e[1;2B"':'printf  "\e[8;%d;%dt" $((LINES+3)) $COLUMNS'
bind -x '"\e[1;2A"':'printf  "\e[8;%d;%dt" $((LINES-3)) $COLUMNS'
```

to be used with respectively: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>
  ,   <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>
  ,   <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>
  or   <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>

**Note**: As this in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) bind, this will work in interactive command environment (aka not under `vim` nor `less`, `read` or any work in progress)